# When using the MediaPlayer API the audio stream stops after a few seconds of playback

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-4.4-kitkat, audioflinger

I'm using Android's MediaPlayer API to play a stream of audio (`http://www.abc.net.au/res/streaming/audio/hls/classic_fm.m3u8`). After a few seconds (sometimes more, sometimes less) my audio stops but not error event is raised.

On Logcat appears this message:

```
06-30 19:35:12.785  24767-25086/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4100) from active list on thread 0xb5e5f008
```

Sometimes after a while a get an error in the video player related to network issues. Sometimes I don't receive anything.

I have checked for GC and power management issues, my internet connection is stable too. Does anyone knows how to resolve this or at least what it really means?

I'm testing this on a Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4. I tested my code before with a previous version of the OS and everything worked fine a long as I remember.

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently this is caused by a bug on Android 4.4.3 and 4.4.4. So there's no fix for that yet. More info: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70877#makechanges